# Bring preformatted paragraphs closer together?

Tags: css, whitespace

I'm using `white-space: pre-wrap` to allow user input to include arbitrary whitespace and have it faithfully reproduced in the output.

However, I feel that the space between paragraphs of text is too big.

Is there any way to specify... I don't know, something like `line-height`, but only for empty lines?

If not, the text is already being parsed for colour codes, so I suppose I could expand the parser to look for paragraphs and wrap them in `<p>` tags instead. That'd work. I'm just wondering if there's a pure CSS solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot select an empty line out of a multiline paragraph in CSS only.

You can [select empty elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3aempty). But I would go with your suggestion to use `p` tags.

Comment: Fair enough. Extending the parser was a little trickier than I anticipated, but it now registers "exactly two newlines" as a paragraph break. Seems to work nicely.